# I need some help on these formulas implementation

Tags: java

I need some help with implementing these formulas. I think I implemented them correctly but for some reason I don't get the expected results:

[image]

This is the code for NMI, I, and H functions respectively.
Are the formulas implemented correctly ?
Thanks

```
int totalN = getTotalN(events);
        double h1 = H(clusters, totalN);
        double h2 = H(events, totalN);
        double valueI = I(clusters, events, totalN);
        double value_NMI = valueI / (double) ((h1 + h2) / (double) 2);
        System.out.println("NMI: " + value_NMI);

static public double I(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> clusters, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> events, int totalN) {

        //store sorted content to contents
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>> it = events.entrySet().iterator();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>> it2 = clusters.entrySet().iterator();

        String key;
        ArrayList<String> event;
        ArrayList<String> cluster;

        double valueI = 0;
        while (it.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> mapItem = it.next();
            key = mapItem.getKey();

            //if cluster doesn't exist
            //if(!clusters.containsKey(key)) continue;
            //cluster = clusters.get(key);

            event = mapItem.getValue();

            while (it2.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> mapItem2 = it2.next();
                cluster = mapItem2.getValue();

            float common_docs = 0;
            for (int i=0; i< event.size(); i++) {   
                for (int j=0; j< cluster.size(); j++) { 
                    if (event.get(i).equals(cluster.get(j))) {
                        common_docs = common_docs + 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


            if (common_docs != 0) valueI = valueI + ( ( common_docs / (float) totalN) * Math.log((common_docs * totalN) / (float) (event.size() * cluster.size())) );       
            }
        }

        return valueI;
    }


    static public double H(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> clusters, int totalN) {

        //store sorted content to contents
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>> it = clusters.entrySet().iterator();
        ArrayList<String> cluster;

        double entropy = 0;
        while (it.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> mapItem = it.next();
            cluster = mapItem.getValue();

            double ratio = cluster.size() / (float) totalN;
            entropy = entropy + ratio * Math.log(ratio);

        }

        return -entropy;
    }

    static public int getTotalN(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> dataset) {

        int totalN = 0;
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>> it = dataset.entrySet().iterator();
        ArrayList<String> item;

        while (it.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> mapItem = it.next();
            item = mapItem.getValue();

            for (int i=0; i< item.size(); i++) {
                totalN = totalN + 1;
            }

        }

        return totalN ;
    }
```

Comment: What test data are you using and what values do you expect to be the result of the calculations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess no. I just checked I(C,E), and there you don't reset it2 in every iteration of it, which would be necessary for the nested sum.

Answer (score 1):

Iterator it2 in method I should be initialize inside the loop on it.
You could simplify your code and avoid this kind of error by using the "foreach" notation:

```
static public double I(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> clusters, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> events, int totalN) {

    String key;
    ArrayList<String> event;
    ArrayList<String> cluster;

    double valueI = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> mapItem: events.entrySet()) {
        key = mapItem.getKey();

        //if cluster doesn't exist
        //if(!clusters.containsKey(key)) continue;
        //cluster = clusters.get(key);

        event = mapItem.getValue();

        for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> mapItem2: clusters.entrySet()) {
            cluster = mapItem2.getValue();

            float common_docs = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < event.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < cluster.size(); j++) {
                    if (event.get(i).equals(cluster.get(j))) {
                        common_docs = common_docs + 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


            if (common_docs != 0) {
                valueI = valueI + ((common_docs / (float) totalN) * Math.log((common_docs * totalN) / (float) (event.size() * cluster.size())));
            }
        }
    }

    return valueI;
}

static public double H(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> clusters, int totalN) {

    //store sorted content to contents
    ArrayList<String> cluster;

    double entropy = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> mapItem: clusters.entrySet()) {
        cluster = mapItem.getValue();

        double ratio = cluster.size() / (float) totalN;
        entropy = entropy + ratio * Math.log(ratio);

    }

    return -entropy;
}

static public int getTotalN(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> dataset) {

    int totalN = 0;
    ArrayList<String> item;

    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> mapItem: dataset.entrySet()) {
        item = mapItem.getValue();

        for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++) {
            totalN = totalN + 1;
        }

    }

    return totalN;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're not getting the expected results because of floating point rounding errors (see [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for further details). I haven't looked at the code in your methods implementing the three functions, but I see that you use `float` and `double`, which may cause you troubles. You may want to use [`BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.

Comment: While avoiding floating point numbers when handling currency values is a good idea, it's not always necessary (or even suggested)! For example in many scientific areas floating point numbers will produce the "more correct" results.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: you're right. My answer is actually a _guess_: I've explicitly stated that I haven't looked at the code, so I might be wrong.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: I wonder how values with rounding errors are "more correct" than those without

Comment: @subsub: IEEE floating point numbers have exactly defined rules of how numbers are calculated and rounded. In order to make calculations reproducible across systems those rules are sometimes much more important than mere precision. Especially if the values measured and calculated are (in-precise) natural measurements in the first place.